# Can a 12 V/24 V device work on 13.6 V DC?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, dc

I have a Dometic CFX3 45 portable fridge that I want to run from my EcoFlow RiverMax Portable Power Station.

I want to charge the fridge via the DC port on the EcoFlow but it doesn't seem to work all of the time. It initially worked, but now it will only work for a few hours and then the fridge shuts down. Also the fridge has previously given a low voltage warning of 11.5 V.

Here are the specs:

**Dometic CFX3 45 Fridge:**
Input voltage (DC) 12/24 V
Rated input current (DC) 8.2 A

**EcoFlow RiverMax:**
Car Power Output (x1)
136 W, 13.6 V DC, 10 A max

So my question is: can I power the fridge from the portable battery, or is the voltage difference a problem? I'm trying to figure out if they are not compatible or if either device needs warranty services.

Comment: Should be no issues.

Comment: "I want to charge the fridge" - charge? Does it have an internal battery?

Answer (score 1):

13.6V should be fine.  It's the voltage on a car electrical system when the engine is running.

I would only expect the fridge to run for a few hours on the EcoFlow RiverMax.  The fridge draws a lot of current, and it will eventually run the battery flat on the EcoFlow RiverMax.  How long that takes may depend on whether the fridge was already cold when you plugged it in.